# How to import a generated python module

Tags: python, import, code-generation

I am generating python modules (using antlr).
e.g. foo_pb2.py, bar_pb2.py

If I generate them into my python source directory; then, importing those modules works as expected.
However, I do not want to contaminate my source directory with generated files; so, I generate the files into a `gen_module` directory.
The problem is how to import those modules?

I have used the approach of modifying the `sys.path` and inserting the `gen_module` path.
I do this in the `__init__.py` of the module which uses the generated code.

Is there a more pythonic approach?

- Put the generated modules is a package?
- Using `import_module`? I have tried it but modules imported from within the imported modules are not found.

Comment: Yep, make an installable package.